# Writing specific key-value pairs from JSON response to CSV

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to build an IPStack API script in Python.  I am having trouble writing the JSON output to a CSV.  (The next stage in this script will be sending more than one ip_address value through, so I need to do this iteratively.)

I am stuck on figuring out how to tell Python which key-value pairs to write to the CSV.  Below is my code followed by the error it sends back.

Would greatly appreciate any insight.

```
import requests
import csv
import json

ip_address = '65.222.2.114'

# key = '?access_key=12345'

full_request = 'http://api.ipstack.com/' + ip_address + '?access_key=12345'

joined_full_request = ''.join(full_request)

r = requests.get(joined_full_request)

output = r.json()

print(output)

with open('/Users/reallymemorable/Desktop/iptest.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['continent_name', 'country_code', 'country_name', 'region_code', 'region_name', 'city', 'zip', 'latitude', 'longitude']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writerow({['continent_name'], ['country_code'], ['country_name'], ['region_code'], ['region_name'], ['city'], ['zip'], ['latitude'], ['longitude']})
```

The error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Also, when I edited my writer.writerow line to do, for example "output['continent_name']", it gave me this error:

```
TypeError: writerow() takes 2 positional arguments but 10 were given
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
writer.writerow({['continent_name'], ['country_code'], ['country_name'], ['region_code'], ['region_name'], ['city'], ['zip'], ['latitude'], ['longitude']})
```

You open with a `{`, which is for dictionaries (`{k1: v1, k2: v2, ...}`), but instead you try to stuff a list inside the two braces.  That doesn't make any sense, and you're getting the error because Python things you're trying to use the list as a dictionary key.

You've created a `DictWriter` instance, which means you need to pass *dictionaries* to the `writerow` method.  So, for example, something like:

```
writer.writerow({'continent_name': 'north america',
                 'country_code': '1',
                 'country_name': 'united states',
                 'region_code': 'foo',
                 'region_name': 'bar',
                 'city': 'boston',
                 'zip': '02110',
                 'latitude': 42,
                 'longitude': -72})
```

If you're trying to write values from a JSON result, it should just be a matter of extracting the necessary key or keys.  If you need more help on that front, you'll need to update your question to show what the JSON content actually looks like.